# Can I run a Scala macro automatically when I extend a given type?

Tags: scala, code-generation, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

Currently, I use a Scala macro annotation to automatically generate some code into a Scala object. It works like this:

```
@constants
object PopoverCommands extends Constants { … }
```

I find it somewhat redundant to have to extend `Constants` and to annotate `PopoverCommands` with `@constants`. I know the macro annotation can insert the `extends Constants` part. My question goes the other way round: is there any way I can run some macro code (e.g. simulate the presence of `@constants`) by simply extending a type (here, `Constants`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't currently possible.